# How to make a page remain and not redirect when downloading a file?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a JSP that has a link, which, when clicked, downloads a file. My problem is that when I click on the link, it goes to blank page and remains there. I would either like for it to return to the page the link was clicked from, or for it download without going to the blank page. Any ideas?

Currently, this is what my code looks like:

```
Please <a href="https://webpath/filename.xls">click here</a> to see an example of a valid file.
```

Comment: Please post some code. -1

Comment: Question edited. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an on click event, make sure that it returns false to stay on the same page.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(/* http://example.com/file.txt */); return false">click me</a>
```

If you are not using javascript, set the target to a blank page using `_blank`.

```
<a href="http://example.com/file.txt" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

Comment: I don't want it to go to blank. I want it remain in the same page that it is getting clicked from. I tried the code you posted, but to no avail. What could be wrong?

Comment: _blank will open a new tab/window

Comment: this will redirect wont work as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have following code that wont redirect and download following is working code

```
function DownloadFileWithoutRedirect() {

    //url must be hosted else cors issue will come
    //url is entire file url - http://doman.com/test.pdf
    var url = window.location.origin+"/docs/test.pdf";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    
    request.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload =  function(e){
            var link = document.createElement("a")
            link.href = e.target.result;
            link.download = "download.pdf";//filename that is kept for dowloading file
            link.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        };
    };
    request.send();
    
}
```

This solution makes a get call and a blob response which will be downloading the file without redirect. Further full code is illustrated in Spring Boot + Thymeleaf
(Solution is not dependent on Java) For avoiding cors its tested in such a way. I hope following will be helpfull

StartWebApplication.java

```
package com.mkyong;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StartWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
package com.mkyong.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    
    @Value("${welcome.message}")
    private String message;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "welcome"; //view
    }


}
```

Welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>

<body>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <button class="btn" value="download" onClick="DownloadFileWithoutRedirect()" >Download</button>
    </div>
    
</main>
<!-- /.container -->


<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{webjars/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

<script>

function DownloadFileWithoutRedirect() {

    //url must be hosted else cors issue will come
    //url is entire file url - http://localhost:1818/docs/test.pdf
    var url = window.location.origin+"/docs/test.pdf";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    
    request.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload =  function(e){
            var link = document.createElement("a")
            link.href = e.target.result;
            link.download = "download.pdf";//filename that is kept for dowloading file
            link.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        };
    };
    request.send();
    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>web-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</description>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <bootstrap.version>4.2.1</bootstrap.version>
        <jquery.version>3.6.4</jquery.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- web mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

This is a sample project from [mkyong](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/) in which onclick file download is incorporated

Answer (score 0):

Is not that hard if the file is already up and you are not generating it on your server side.

Call an href an set a name to the file:

```
<a class="badge text-bg-primary" href="your_file_link.txt" download="suggested_file_name">Button text</a>
```

Is this helpful? Let me know.